# Spring equivalent of @Stateless EJB with multiple @PersistenceContext

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

I've been banging my head on the wall for the past couple of days trying to get this to work but I've not been able to.

I wrote a JPA EntityManagerProvider recently using EJB:

**EntityManagerProviderBean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class EntityManagerProviderBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PU1")
    private EntityManager entityManager1;   

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PU2")
    private EntityManager entityManager2;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return (...) ? entityManager1: entityManager2;
    }
}
```

And then of course I can inject the EJB wherever needed like this:

**UserFacade.java**

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacade {

    @EJB
    private EntityManagerProviderBean emProvider;
    private EntityManager em = emProvider.getEntityManager();

    ...
}
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar using Spring, using annotations, and without doing anything in XML.  I can't seem to figure out a way to inject the EntityManager. Anything that I do leads to a NullPointerException. For example, I tried to inject the EntityManager manually without relying on my EntityManagerProviderBean, like this:

**UserFacadeSpring.java**

```
public class UserFacadeSpring {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PU1")
    private EntityManager em;

    ...
}
```

But this gives me a NullPointerException. So the EntityManager is not being injected at all and I'm not sure what's wrong.

So two questions basically:

1. How can I inject the EntityManager using Spring?
2. How can I use my existing EntityManagerProviderBean EJB in Spring? What modifications do I need to make?

Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated. As you can tell I'm a complete noob to Spring. I tried to read the guide but everything's flying over my head at the moment. I actually did try to do something half-baked but it didn't work either (I either get NullPointerException or BeanNotFoundException, I must have used every combination of @Component, @Bean, @Autowired annotations I think!):

**EntityManagerProviderSpring.java**

```
@Component
public class EntityManagerProviderSpring {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PU1")
    private EntityManager entityManager1;   

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PU2")
    private EntityManager entityManager2;

    @Bean
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return (...) ? entityManager1: entityManager2;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EntityManagerProviderSpring.class);
    EntityManagerProviderSpring emProvider = context.getBean(EntityManagerProviderSpring.class);
    EntityManager em = emProvider.getEntityManager();

    ...
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using Hibernate with JPA and the following is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PU1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="pu1_username"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pu1_pwd"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="PU2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Basically you are asking, how to configure spring, so that it injects multiple PersistenceContexts. Google for "spring two entity managers".

Comment: Thanks, but there are still things that are not making sense. Does there absolutely need to be some sort of context.xml file describing the beans? I'm using Hibernate with JPA2 and have a persistence.xml file where the datasource is defined so I would have though that this would be sufficient?

Comment: This stuff is fairly basic. Have a look at the spring docs.

Answer (score 5):

To have the exact same functionality on dependency injection level, it is impossible to map stateless ejb bean to a spring bean.

> EJB @Singleton -> Spring @Component (or @Service or @Controller or @Repository)
>
> EJB @Stateful -> Spring @Component@Scope("prototype") (or @Service@Scope("prototype") or @Controller@Scope("prototype") or @Repository@Scope("prototype"))
>
> EJB @Stateless -> DOES NOT EXIST IN SPRING.

Stateless beans are very handy for this multiple persistence contexts... However, since Spring doesn't offer stateless bean. You have to use custom Spring setup to apply multiple persistence context. It won't work with only persistence.xml like EJB, unfortunately :(.

So to answer your questions:

1. Read Spring doc... Plenty of examples everywhere. Shortly, In Spring 4 Java Config you can use `@EnableTransactionManagement`, a transaction manager and an entity manager factory per persistence context.
2. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html. This is how you do it. Not a nice way since using `jndi`, but it is a solution...